Listening to the Ticking of a Symfony made checkbox with javascript
I need to listen to the click of a checkbox created and displayed in the view through Symfony5 formBuilder and within a sonataAdminBundle interface. The point of this being to adapt some other field content and futur behavior when the user has set this checkbox to "true". I cannot find a way to make it effective. Please note that I have very limited experience with javascript.
I create this checkbox in my controller and I set its class with twig renderig attributes :
{{ form_widget(form.sameAddress,{'id':"js-same_add_check", 'attr':{'class':"js-add_check"}}) }} 

The problem is that with the way Symfony displays the checkbox, this class name does not point at the dynamic input object. Inspecting my page, I see it this way :
<div class="icheckbox_square-blue" style="position: relative;"><input type="checkbox" id="js-same_add_check" name="form[sameAddress]" class="js-add_check" value="1" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="js-same_add_check" name="form[sameAddress]" class="js-add_check" value="1" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
    <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
</div>

The dynamic checkBox in the view is actually represented by this  tag bearing the class "iCheck-helper". But this class seems invisible to javascript. Here is my JS snippet :
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('READY!!');
            var sameCheck = document.querySelector('.js-add_check');

            sameCheck.addEventListener('change', function() {
                console.log('In listened event');
                if (this.checked) {
                    console.log("Checkbox is checked..");
                } else {
                    console.log("Checkbox is not checked..");
                }
        });

In this state, JS has effectively selected the js-add_check tag. But no clicks triggers the event, only "READY!!" is displaid in my console logs (note that I have also tried with onClick event and that only one tag in my view has the js-add_check class).
I have tried this same logic pointing at the ins tag (class "iCheck-helper"). But it throws an exception with the addEventListener => Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
Then I tried to point at the parent div (class "icheckbox_square-blue") with the intent to get my dynamic element by looping ist childs. Here again, it's like "icheckbox_square-blue" does not exist within my view.
I feel I miss some key techniques to navigate the DOM created by Symfony FormBuilder...
Can you guide me through listening that checkbox ticking and content with Javascript ?

Doesn't iCheck have callbacks that you can listen to?

@julian Koster - I've tried every way of getting it through the DOM that I knew but could not succeed this way. In hindsight I think it might be a sonataAdminBundle related problem because I realized I had no problem doing what I wanted when recreating my method through a pure Symfony path. For the sonata solution, I had to recreate what I wanted in HTML directly on the view without going through the formbuilder. You can see my answer for more details.

This problem of display could be sonata related because I realized I had no problem doing what I wanted when recreating my method through a pure Symfony path. I have managed to still get what I wanted in the sonata view by hardcoding the problematics elements in pure HTML. I have a custom div whose click event I can listen to and that :
•   switches an css made checkbox existing for visual confirmation only
•   switches a variable from false to true (and vice versa) which guide the JS action when the event is clicked
I had no problem seeing the other fields of the form for the rest of my script.

use comment section to make addition to your question.
